# Codeigniter URL redirection and routing, pagination redirect to listinag page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, routes

I'am new to Codeigniter
My listing page redirect to detail page 
listing page with pagination

```
url => holida.local/destinations/explore/all-destinations/3
```

all-destination mean category name

my destination detail page

```
url => holida.local/destinations/explore/hill-country/badulla
```

i change my routs as ---

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';

$route['destinations/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "destinations/detail/$1/$1";
```

when i click pagination next button redirect it detail page (it should be go listing page) without route pagination working correctly

Comment: did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this - **UPDATED**:

```
$route['destinations/detail/(:any)/(:any)'] = "destinations/detail/$1/$2";
$route['destinations/explore/(:any)/(:any)'] = "destinations/explore/$1/$2";
```

Comment: I try this one but all so same issue

Comment: @Beliya: what is your controller name and function name that you are routing?

Comment: as per my understanding, your controller name is destinations and function name is detail() correct me if i am wrong

Comment: class Destinations,  and there is two function explore, detail

Comment: allright, and which function do you want to use with this url? explore or detail?

Comment: both destinations/explore/hill-country/badulla like this  badulla mean detail function

Answer (score 0):

This working

$route['destinations/explore/(:any)/(:num)'] = "destinations/explore/$1/$2";
$route['destinations/explore/(:any)/(:any)'] = "destinations/detail/$1/$1";